# Symfony2 dynamically assign controller for specific route

Tags: php, symfony, routes, router

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this problem in the correct way

I need the same route pattern for 2 different actions, like this

```
/{category}
```

going to productAction and

```
/{brand}
```

going to brandAction (without prefix)

A query to DB will tell me which type of entity this parameter is and then I can assign the action/controller to handle it

1. I could create an Action to handle this pattern and redirect to another action accordingly
2. I could create a **Listener in kernel.controller** event and reassign the controller accordingly
3. I could use **Symfony CMF** but seems to me like overkill.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Option 2 should work just fine.

Comment: Do you really have to do this? Seems like making your code more complicated that it needs to be. Ideally you'd have the format `{resource}/{identifier}`

Comment: Yes, but for SEO reasons we're looking to have these routes without extra parameters for Id or type. I'm not sure what's best for SEO but this is a product requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using Option 2, not sure if that is the best way to do it

```
    /**
 * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
 */
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $routeService = $this->getRouteService();
    $params = $request->attributes->all();
    $slugs = array();

    foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
        if (preg_match('/slug*/', $key)) {
            $node = $routeService->findBySlug($param);
            if ($node !== null) {
                $slug['id'] = $node->getEntityId();
                $slug['type'] = $node->getEntityType();
                $slugs[] = $slug;
            }
        }
    }

    $request->request->set('slugs', $slugs);
}
```